# Can I have schemes specific routes in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I want to serve a page if the scheme is https and throw a 404 if not. Is this possible in Symfony routing?

http ://mysite.com/api/members <- should throw 404

and

http**s** ://mysite.com/api/members <- should work

The following route that I use is doing an automatic redirection for http, instead of 404:

```
acme_two_index:
    path:     /api/members
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTestBundle:Default:members }
    schemes:  [https]
    methods:  [GET]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in addition to your existing route but I'm worried about its efficacy since the `schemes` parameter is meant to force the route to a particular protocol:

```
acme_two_index_notfound:
    path:     /api/members
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTestBundle:Default:membersNotFound }
    schemes:  [http]
    methods:  [GET]
```

and make a separate controller in your `DefaultController.php`:

```
public function membersNotFoundAction()
{
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('Page not found for this protocol');
    return; // Just in case Symfony needs to see a return
}
```

You may need to instead just allow all schemes in the routing and handle it within the controller:

```
acme_two_index:
    path:     /api/members
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTestBundle:Default:members }
    methods:  [GET]
```

and

```
public function membersAction()
{
    if (!$this->get('request')->isSecure()) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Page not found for this protocol');
    }
    // ... rest of your code
}
```

Comment: First option does not work and it appears the second one is the only work around at the moment. I'll see if I can open a feature request. Thanks